# Locking fields on a content type

Tags: nodes, entities

Using Drupal 7:

I have several content types with their own sets of fields, but I also have a set of fields that they must all share in common. That is easy enough through the administrative UI, but I'm writing a module that programmatically will add the fields to all node content types that I specify. Additionally, I do not want the administrator to be able to remove or edit those fields through the administrative UI.

How can I make it so that as an administrator is managing content types that the admin cannot modify or remove these fields that I have specified?

Alternatively, I know that I can create a separate entity and force field existence that way, but then I loose access to a lot of the functionality already built into the node entity, especially the function hook_node_access which is also a requirement for this module.

Anyone have any suggestions or know how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to the field api documentation [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/group/field/7). You do not have to add permissions to block the delete. All you need to do is add the "locked" attribute to the field definition.

> locked (integer): Whether or not the field is available for editing.
>   If TRUE, users can't change field settings or create new instances of
>   the field in the UI. Defaults to FALSE.

Comment: Awesome. That is way easier than I thought it would be. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

There is a module for that names "[Field Lock](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_lock)".

Of course it uses the API field definition "[locked](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/group/field/7)" as mentioned before.

Here is a short description from the module page:

> Field lock adds additional level of permissions so certain users can
>   lock a field, enter code herepreventing others from editing or
>   deleting it.

Answer (score 0):

For existing fields that are provided by (eg, media_gallery or commerce)
You can run-once the snippet from http://atlantic-canary.net/es/how-to-lockunlock-a-field-in-drupal

```
<?php
$field_name = 'field_name';
$field = field_read_field($field_name);
$field['locked'] = 0; // 0: unlock; 1: lock.
field_update_field($field);
?>
```

I did it for myself in an update hook, to ensure that my extension to media_gallery could expose some settings.

```
/**
 * UNLOCK the description field provided by media_gallery so we can tweak settings.
 */
function niwa_media_update_7002() {
  $field = field_read_field('media_description');
  $field['locked'] = FALSE;
  field_update_field($field);
}
```

In my case I just wanted to limit the text formats that were available as an image caption, as full_HTML was causing problems. better_formats.module could not help me until I'd unlocked the field.